# Reading gzip file that is currently being written to

Tags: python, file, io, gzip

My program does a lot of file processing, and as the files are large I prefer to write them as GZIP.  One challenge is that I often need to read files as they are being written.  This is not a problem without GZIP compression, but when compression is on, the reading complains about failed CRC, which I presume might have something to do with compression info not being flushed properly when writing.  Is there any way to use GZIP with Python such that, when I write and flush to a file (but not necessarily close the file), that it can be read as well?

Answer (score 1):

I think flushing data to file (compressed) just writes the data into file, but headers are written only on `close()`, so you need to close the file first, and only after you can open it and read all data you need. If you need to write large data ammounts, you can try to use database, like *PostgreSQL* or *MySQL* where you can specify table with compression (archive, compressed), and you will be able to insert data into the table, and read it, database software will do all rest for you (compression, decompression on inserts, selects).

Comment: Is there an alternative compressor that does not need to write headers?

Comment: file system with compression, you can write files simply, and all care for compression will take FS. For example ZFS - supports LZJB and gzip.